# Deployment error when using Laravel Forge

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, environment-variables, laravel-forge

Within Laravel Forge, on `Quick Deploy` or `Deploy`, I'm presented with this error within the deployment log:

```
Generating autoload files
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Illuminate\Support\Arr' not found in
/home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php
on line 182

PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/forge/default/artisan:0
PHP   2. require_once() /home/forge/default/artisan:30
PHP   3. Illuminate\Foundation\Application->detectEnvironment() /home/forge/default/bootstrap/start.php:33
PHP   4. Illuminate\Foundation\EnvironmentDetector->detect() /home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:262
PHP   5. Illuminate\Foundation\EnvironmentDetector->detectConsoleEnvironment() /home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/EnvironmentDetector.php:18
PHP   6. Illuminate\Foundation\EnvironmentDetector->getEnvironmentArgument() /home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/EnvironmentDetector.php:68
PHP   7. array_first() /home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/EnvironmentDetector.php:89
```

I have set up the application correct to the best of my knowledge, including `Environment Variables` and Environment Detection:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(
array( 

     'development' => array('Thor','localhost'), 
     'production' => array('Removed for security')
));
```

On the actual website, once the deployment has (apparantly!) taken place, this is the error log:

[image: Error on website]

My complete `start.php` code is:

```
<?php

$app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application;

$env = $app->detectEnvironment(
    array( 

         'development' => array('Thor','localhost'), 
         'production' => array('removed for security')
    ));

$app->bindInstallPaths(require __DIR__.'/paths.php');

$framework = $app['path.base'].'/vendor/laravel/framework/src';

require $framework.'/Illuminate/Foundation/start.php';

return $app;
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your laravel system is trying to instantiate the class `Illuminate\Support\Arr` -- however, when it tries to it can't find the class, and PHP fails with a fatal exception.

The first step to debugging this problem is to

1. Make sure the class file is where it's supposed to be
2. Make sure the class name and path match the file name

The class `Illuminate\Support\Arr` normally lives in

```
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Arr.php
```

and is defined with the name `Arr`

```
class Arr { ... }
```

Step one would be making sure this file exists, and actually defines the class.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Alan Storm. You're quite right, the file doesn't exist, but only that file? I'm unsure why a composer update would miss that file out? It appears on my localhost, even after an update, and also within the master git branch?

Comment: Sounds like a question for forge support.

Comment: Already logged, I will post the answer here if I am successful in solving it.

Comment: It appears that this file is new in 4.2, but my composer states 4.2.*, which is weird. Looking at my composer.lock, it states 4.1. Even if I delete my composer.lock to regenerate it, it goes back to 4.1! Interesting?

Comment: Don't know enough about forge or your setup to say.

Comment: Did you solve the issue? It could be a local cache for composer that now remembers 4.1 or another dependency is forcing 4.1 as you don't mind which one you get because you have 4.2.*